# Bully Scholarship Editon: What happens if I press restart in the pause menu?

Tags: pc, bully

I recently re-downloaded bully on my computer and completed the game! I want to play it again, but I was wondering if I press restart will that delete my previous save? I don't want to lose my progress I just want to play through the game again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've only played original Bully, so this may be wrong in Scholarship edition.

You can have up to six save files in original Bully (I don't know about Scholarship edition, but I bet it won't be lower than 6.) When you start the game, you start on the last opened save file. Let's say that this is your original save file.

In the pause menu, you can hit *Restart*, which will start a new save file.  You can then save the new save file to a different slot. This action(Restart) alone won't delete your original save file, but if you accidentally overwrite your original save file with your new save file, the original will be gone. So be careful when choosing slot. Or maybe save your original save file to another slot before hitting Restart, so that you can have backup.

If you start on your new save file (as I said earlier, the game starts with last opened save file, so it'll be likely your new save file) but want to play your original save file, you can choose to load your file from the pause menu (it's at above of Restart.)